# Tools for managing Text Templates / Boilerplate Code or Snippets?

Tags: email, templates, text, code-snippets

I am looking for freely available tools to help manage text templates (e.g. for writing emails or other letters), boilerplate code and other snippets.

Preferably something open source or at least freeware.

Ideally, it would not be specific to managing source code, but would generally help manage all sorts of ASCII chunks (or maybe even RTF?).

Either something web based or cross-platform (Linux/Win32).

For example, I keep writing certain letters that would really only need to be slightly customized (e.g. change date, name, un/select certain phrases).

Any good pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

--- code ---
For vim: [SnipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540)
For Emacs: [yasnippets](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/)

--- non code ---
For general purpose snippets in windows: [Texter](http://lifehacker.com/238306/lifehacker-code-texter-windows)